# Internal error 500 on centos 7.5 (vesta). Timeout?

Tags: linux, server, centos, timeout, vesta

After more or less 90 seconds of running script via browser (I need to do it via browser - real big report) I get 500 server internal error.

I suspect this is simple timeout issue, I tried in php:
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 900); //900 sekund == 5 minut`
but it didn't help - from what I read server can override php in this.

I'm not a server guy. Could sombody tell me how to set apache/vesta to have 15 minutes timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out vesta has not only apache but also NGINX instaled (I don't know why, could somebody explain? Especialy that I saw vesta instal link and it was set to `nginx no`).

open `etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and set

```
proxy_read_timeout 900;
proxy_connect_timeout 900;
proxy_send_timeout 900;
```

then `sudo systemctl restart nginx to restart`

some more info: https://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?t=11439